# New added in app items showing as not purchasable

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm having trouble adding new in app items to my app.
App is live for 1.5 month now with one in app item.
All works fine with the first one I added.

Added 2 more items in my console two days ago but none of them are purchasable.

[image: error]

log:

> 09-05 17:46:26.868 25260-25300/? E/Volley: [569] c.a: Unexpected response code 404 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/ees/preparePurchase
>   09-05 17:46:26.870 25260-25260/? I/Finsky: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkang.png) com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.ah.a(457): Error: PurchaseError{type=2 subtype=0}
>   09-05 17:46:26.870 25260-25260/? I/Finsky: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkang.png) com.google.android.finsky.billing.lightpurchase.ah.a(460): Purchase failed: PurchaseError{type=2 subtype=0}

I'm not even able to get the skudetails from them.

```
List additionalSkuList = new ArrayList();
additionalSkuList.add(ITEM_SKU);
additionalSkuList.add(ITEM_SKU_2);
additionalSkuList.add(ITEM_SKU_3);

mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, null,
    new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Log.e(TAG, result.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.purchases_not_availabe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String item = inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU).getPrice();

            String item_2 = "- not available -";
            String item_3 = "- not available -";

            SkuDetails detail = inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU_2);
            if(detail != null)
                 item_2 = inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU_2).getPrice();

            detail = inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU_3);
            if(detail != null)
                item_3 = inventory.getSkuDetails(ITEM_SKU_3).getPrice();


            ....
        }
    }
```

[image: not available]

I'm really lost. New items are active in the developer console.
I tried to upload a new beta version in the hope that the new items will show up, didn't work either though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after two days I fixed it now. ofc, 5 minutes after I posted here...

Initially I added the new in app items with my admin account and not owner account...but I also changed the naming a bit. initially my new items had the same name of my first (working) item as prefix in it's name.
I assume it was the owner account that fixed it though, can't say for sure though.